# MYSQL AES_DECRYPT function work with heidiSQL but when i run the same query in my C# program always return DBNULL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using MariaDB for my db and I have a users table with `ID`, `User`, and `Pass` columns. The `pass` column is AES_Encrypted and I can read all the fields with the following query executed in heidiSQL:

```
SELECT ID, User, AES_DECRYPT(Pass, 'mykey') AS Pass FROM DeviceUser WHERE ID = 1
```

The client is coded in C#:

```
string query = "SELECT ID, User, AES_DECRYPT(Pass, '@key') AS Pass FROM DeviceUser WHERE ID = @id";

var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DB.Conexion);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", MariaDB.DBEncrypkey);
cmd.Prepare();

MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    DeviceUser user = new SqlDataReaderMapper<DeviceUser>(rdr).Build(); //i can not get the pass in this line
    users.Add((user));
}
rdr.Close();
```

But in my C code the pass property always has DBnull value and if I change the data reader mapper to read the pass column directly like:

```
string pass = rdr.GetString("Pass");
```

It throw a SqlNullValueException the problem should be in the AES_DECRYPT function because if i change the query to:

```
string query = "SELECT ID, User, Pass FROM DeviceUser WHERE ID = @id";
```

I can read the value in the C# program (obiously encrypted) but as the original query runs fine in heidySQL I can not find why is returning DBNull in C#.

Comment: Enable General log temporarily and look actual query code sent to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
string query = "SELECT ID, User, AES_DECRYPT(Pass, @key) AS Pass FROM DeviceUser WHERE ID = @id";
```

You want to use the *value* of the parameter `@key`, not the *literal* `'@key'`.

Comment: You are right, i had it like that originaly but the SqlDataReaderMapper throw a converting exeption  when i do it as you said, i thought that the exepcion was caused by the wrong lecture because it is a string but i just verified that the problem is with the SqlDataReaderMapper because if i get the string withouht the mapper it works. Thank you

Comment: @Freespirit I don't know what `SqlDataReaderMapper` is, but: have you tried "Dapper"? it might be a good fit here: `var users = DB.Conexion.Query<User>("select ...", new {id, key = MariaDB.DBEncrypkey}).AsList();`

Comment: i downloaded the mapper from the nuget packt manager, https://github.com/grigorgeous/sqldatareader-mapper/   but once again i realized the error was realy simple, there is no problem with the mapper, even when i save the pass colum as varchar or blob the result of the AES_DECRYPT always return a byte array so the mapper can not cast it to a string and throw an exception. but i will read abouth the dapper thank you.